# A problem which involves counting the number of particles in a fancy experiment.

Tags: combinatorics

I am preparing for an examination and I have got stuck with this question.

It says: " At time t=0 a particle is at point 0 on the real number line. At time t=1 unit the particle divides into two and instantaneously after division, one particle moves to the left and the other moves one unit to the right. At time 2 units each of these particles divide into 2 and one of the new particles move one unit to the left and the other moves one unit to the right. Whenever two particles meet,they destroy each other leaving nothing behind. How many particles will be there after time  2^(11)+1?"

[image]

Above is the picture by which I was trying to find out some pattern though the number of observations is very low. And
even if I could have figured out some pattern it still needed to be proved,which I think is out of my reach.
So please help me by providing a solution to this problem or a helpful hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the pattern when $t=2^1$, $t=2^2$, $t=2^3$.  Can you predict and then prove the pattern at $t=2^n$?  What about $t=2^n+1$?

Comment: If you want a proof, consider binomial coefficients and whether they are even or odd

Comment: The particles do leave at least photons behind when they destroy each other :-)

Comment: @Henry yes I have predicted the pattern correctly and I think that pattern can be proved by help of induction on 'n'. Thanks for the help. But can you explain me how considering binomial coefficients can help me prove the pattern?

Comment: @It'sprobable ${2^n \choose k}$ is even for $1 \le k \le 2^n-1$ because you never manage to get enough powers of $2$ in the denominator of $\frac{(2^n)!}{k!(2^n-k)!}$ to offset those in the numerator, coming closest when $k=2^{n-1}$